# Pinescript - Advanced Strategy with limit orders

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have an Indicator which plots a daily /weekly range for a stock. Two minimum price levels, two max price levels.

`

```
//plot daily band 1 
ud=plot(dayUpper, title="Day Upper 1", color=color.gray)
ld=plot(dayLower, title="Day Lower 1", color=color.green)

//plot daily band 2 - deviation

ud1=plot(dayUpper1, title="Day Upper 4", color=color.gray)
ld1=plot(dayLower1, title="Day Lower 4", color=color.green)
```

`

"dayUpper","dayLower" are constant calculated values during the day and recalculated for new day open.
I included a screen shot of the indicators output.

What i want to do is to create a strategy script with limit orders without no knowledge of pinescript :)

Create orders :

- ex: long limit orders for the min daily range/shorts for the max daily prices (i want to do pyramid (limit orders inside the zones but if that gets too complex lets ignore it)
- if a price hits any of them enter position.
- stop loss : the price violates deviation price, or could be a constant %3 for the simplicty.
- Cancel all orders (if any position is not entered) after 2 days. Basically it should maintain yesterday daily range and todays.
- Take profit : It might be kind of tricky since it must be dynamic. Lets say if script enters a position at monday, while maintaining the stop order, it should adjust the tp limit order to the new days value.
- the script might be long only or short only. It is ideal to select from input screen.

Any example code or reference would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance for any assistance.

https://imgur.com/LIcE2m0  "sample tradingview image"